# $scope.$watch whole form, but get old value only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I want to use $scope.$watch on my whole form inputs and detect changes and then show alert "Data has changed. Please save". The problem is that I want to pass oldValue only when the data is get from the server.

```
$http({
        method: "post",
        url: "url",
        data: {
            Pages: {
                id: pageId
            }
        },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data.editedPage.jkOutputContainer.editedPage.pagesObject;

        $scope.$watch('data',function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if(newValue != oldValue) {
                $scope.dataHasChanged = true;
            } else {
                $scope.dataHasChanged = false;
            }
        }, true);
    });
```

I could use ng-init and ng-change on every input in my form, but i would like to use the $scope.$watch on form.

EDIT: In short i want to hide alert when user back his changes to the state it was get from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.watch('[formname]', checkChanged, true)
function checkChanged(newVal) {
    if (!angular.equals(newVal,$scope.data)) warnUser()
}
```

^This will watch every expression in the form and alert the user

Comment: Hi, this approach looks nice but it is not working. The oldValue changes every time i type something in input.

Comment: Try $scope.formData = angular.copy($scope.data) for the actual form data, and use $scope.data to compare it to. Just to make sure you're not inserting a reference to $scope.data in your form.

Comment: Your solution with copy function is working. Thank you. 

This is my whole code:

`$scope.data = data.editedPage.jkOutputContainer.editedPage.pagesObject;
        $scope.formData = angular.copy($scope.data);


        $scope.$watch('data',function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if(!angular.equals(newValue, $scope.formData)) {
                $scope.dataHasChanged = true;
            } else {
                $scope.dataHasChanged = false;
            }
        }, true);`

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, don't bind the server's response to a `$scope` variable, but just assign it to a variable that is referenced in the script. Here's an example.

```
$http({
  method: "post",
  url: "url",
  data: {
      Pages: {
          id: pageId
      }
  },
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).success(function(data) {

  // To solve your problem, just store the server data in a variable.
  var fromServer = data.editedPage.jkOutputContainer.editedPage.pagesObject;
  $scope.data = fromServer; //<- Reference the var here.

  $scope.$watch('data',function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if(newValue != fromServer) { //<- Reference the var here.
          $scope.dataHasChanged = true;
      } else {
          $scope.dataHasChanged = false;
      }
  }, true);
});
```

Hope that was helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. However it doesn't seems to work. It works when i pass fromServer as a parameter of $scope.$watch but the function still compares the actual data. When i type something in input is started to be the oldValue. In other hand when i leave $scope.$watch parameters and refer the 'fromServer' in condition the function is not working.